# How can I combine LEFT and WEEKDAY formulas in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to combine two formulas in Google Sheets but so far have had no luck.

I have a date `07/03/2019 16:02:19` and I'm trying to create a formula which will allow me to remove the time and let me know the date of the start of the week.

So far I have:

```
=left(B2,len(B2)-8)

=B2-WEEKDAY(B2;3)
```

However, I'd ideally like to have a single formula. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

```
=TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(B2-WEEKDAY(B2, 3)))
```

[image: 0]